# How do I construct a basis for the orthogonal complement of a subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

I was told that i can make a matrix A with vectors that span the subspace W which makes my the column space of my matrix equal to W. Then I can take the Null Space of A transpose which gives me (1,2,3,1). Does this mean the dim is one and it's automatically a basis because there is one vector?

Comment: How can a matrix be equal to a vector space?

Comment: i meant to say the column space of the matrix would equal W

Answer (score 1):

You have line spanned by the vector $v=[2,1,-6,18]^t.$ Then 
$$W^{\perp } = \{w \in \mathbb{R}^4: w\cdot v=0 \}\\
=\{w\in \mathbb{R}^4:2w_1+w_2-6w_3+18w_4=0\}.$$
If you fix $w_2 = \alpha, w_3= \beta, w_4 = \gamma$ then 
$$\begin{bmatrix} w_1 \\
w_2\\
w_3\\
w_4
\end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix} -\alpha/2+3\beta-9\gamma \\
\alpha\\
\beta\\
\gamma
\end{bmatrix}=
 \alpha\begin{bmatrix} -1/2 \\
1\\
0\\
0
\end{bmatrix} +  \beta \begin{bmatrix} 3 \\
0\\
1\\
0
\end{bmatrix} + \gamma \begin{bmatrix} -9 \\
0\\
0\\
1
\end{bmatrix}.$$
So the space $W^{\perp}$ is spanned by the vectors $$(-1/2,1,0,0), (3,0,1,0), (-9,0,0,1)$$
and its dimension is $3.$

Comment: How would I construct a basis for W?

Comment: The basis of $W$ is simply the vector spanning it $(2,1,-6,18).$

Comment: I was given this explanation, If you have a basis for W, and take A to be the matrix with columns span those basis vectors, then the column space of A is W. Thus the perpendicular complement of W is exactly the perpendicular complement of Col(A), which we know is Null(A) Transpose. Wouldn't this yield a different answer?

Comment: @SamuraiBale It in fact yields the same answer, up to sign.

Comment: how would this matrix look like?